# git diff changed files in x commits of a branch

Tags: git, branch, diff

The task is to output files that have been changed in last 5 commits of the `origin/1.5.0` branch.

Without the branch requirement I came up with: `git diff --name-only HEAD~5`. With the branch requirement I tried `git diff --name-only HEAD~5 --first-parent origin/1.5.0` but the output is longer. Adding condition shouldn't produce more results which means there's something I don't understand. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: How about git diff --name-only origin/1.5.0~5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `git diff` command always<sup>1</sup> compares two commits-or-file-trees.  The *options and arguments* select *which* two (and how to do the diff, e.g., `--name-only` or `--name-status` skips the patch part of the diff).

If you run `git diff HEAD~5`, the two things you selected are:

1. `HEAD~5`: the commit five steps back from `HEAD`, the current commit
2. the current work-tree

For comparison, if you run `git diff --cached HEAD~5`, you select instead `HEAD~5` and the current *index*, and if you run `git diff HEAD~10 HEAD~5` you select instead `HEAD~10` and `HEAD~5`.

Note that the `~number` syntax comes from [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).  A tilde suffix followed by an integer may be applied to any other commit selector, such as a raw hash ID, the name `HEAD`, the name of one of your own branches or tags, or the name of any of your *remote-tracking branches*.  Since `origin/1.5.0` is the name of a remote-tracking branch, you can use that to specify the commit to which that name points, or add a tilde and a number to move that many first-parent steps back from that point.

Hence:

```
git diff --name-only origin/1.5.0~5 origin/1.5.0
```

will compare the two specified commits, showing only the names of files that are not the same in those two commits.

---

<sup>1</sup>You can make it behave differently in some interesting cases, but they are not the ones we care about here.

Answer (score 0):

I think with "origin/1.5.0", the command changed to compare HEAD~5 with the branch origin/1.5.0. That is a much different diff than without branch.

Comment: Ok, that actually could make sense. So how should I approach the task?